# Laravel Query: Php implode array string values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Currently I have this variable

`$arrays = implode(", ", $request->pmChck);`

and If I try to return this variable. I will be getting this kind of output

`2019-100,2018-100`

As you can see the values are separated by commas

Now in my laravel query, I'm trying to get all the records of the employee except for these two `company_id` above.

`$pm_selected = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * FROM view_employee_info WHERE company_id NOT IN('".$arrays."')");`

The query is not working, it shows all the data and also the data with the `company_id` of `2019-100 and 2018-100`

It should listing all the data except for these two `company_id` `2019-100 and 2018-100`

Is there anything wrong with my format or syntax?

Comment: When you wrap a comma-separated string in quotes,  you are only passing one value.  `NOT IN ()` is processing a single entry, but you mean to feed it two.  You need to quote wrap each entry in the list.  I'll find a duplicate to close with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imploded array looks like 
`2019-100, 2018-100`
and so is query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM view_employee_info WHERE company_id NOT IN('2019-100, 2018-100')
```

try imploding like this:

```php
implode("', '", $arr)
```

And query will be ok:

```sql
SELECT * FROM view_employee_info WHERE company_id NOT IN('2019-100', '2018-100')
```

Comment: I tied this `implode("', '", $arr)` based on your answer and it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$request->pmChck` is an array of companies you want to exclude, the query will be :

```
DB::table(..)->select(..)->whereNotIn('company_id', $request->pmChck)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query are the single quotes in the IN part.

If you change from

```
$pm_selected = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * FROM view_employee_info WHERE company_id NOT IN('".$arrays."')");
```

To

```
$pm_selected = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * FROM view_employee_info WHERE company_id NOT IN(".$arrays.")");
```

it should work as you expect it. It currently does not work, because your query would be like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE company_id IN ('123, 234')
```

which would treat your input values as a single value, `123, 234`